# React Typescript Argument of type 'x' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<x]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-functional-component

Here is the code

trying to compile it says "Argument of type 'toDo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<toDo[]>'"

i cannot figure out how it is not working since the type seem to be correct.

How to avoid that error

````
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<toDo[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadToDoList()
  }, [])

  const loadToDoList = async () => {
    const toDoList = await ToDoService.getToDoList()
    console.log(toDoList)

    setTodoList(toDoList)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ToDoList items={todoList} />
    </div>
  )
}```
````

Comment: It seems as `toDoList` has the `toDo` type and not `toDo[]`.

Comment: What is the return type of `ToDoService.getToDoList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are trying to set the state with a variable with a type `toDo` when it expects an array of toDo `toDo[]`.

Confirm that the type of `toDoList` returned by `await ToDoService.getToDoList()` is equal to `toDo[]` or change your generic type declaration on the `useState` call to `const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<toDo>([])`, in case `toDo` is already an array.

Comment: If they change the `useState` type declaration to `const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<toDo>([])` then there would still be a TS error. The generic type, `toDo`, is not an array, whilst you're assigning an empty array as the initial value.

Comment: We cannot know which type is `toDo`. Since its the return type of a method called `getTodoList` , there are many chances it is an array

Comment: Based on the error message "Argument of type **'toDo'** is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction< **toDo[]** >'" we certainly know that it's not an array.

Comment: That's not true. `toDO` can perfectly be an array, then `toDo[]` would be an array of arrays.